# How to use php preg_replace or preg_match strip <p> that wrap <pre

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

i have this html

```
<p>some text.</p>
<p><pre>
<?php sample(); 
$var = 'aaa';
?>
</pre></p>
<p>describe</p>
<p>
<pre>
<html>...</html>
</pre>
</p>
```

you will notice that `<pre>` is in `<p>` that is wrong!

i want to remove all `<p>` that wrap `<pre>` not normal `<p>` paragraph.

how to use php correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried and found that this code works.

```
$content = 'as see in question';

$pattern = '#<p>(\\s*)(<pre.*/pre>)(\\s*)</p>#isU';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, '$2', $content);

echo $content;
```